# PMA-SQL-ERROR while importing database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xampp

While importing database in xampp I get these errors

SQL query:

```
<!-- PMA-SQL-ERROR -->
    <div class="error"><h1>Error</h1>
<p><strong>SQL query:</strong>
<a href="db_sql.php?sql_query=SHOW+TABLE+STATUS+FROM+%60berty12_embrace%60+WHERE+Name+%3D+%27wp_pTC_logs%27&amp;show_query=1&amp;db=berty12_embrace&amp;token=753b2640358f750ff66cbbe34e72abd6"><span class="nowrap"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Edit" alt="Edit" class="icon ic_b_edit" /> Edit</span></a>    </p>
<p>
<code class="sql"><pre>
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `berty12_embrace` WHERE Name = 'wp_pTC_logs'
</pre></code>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>MySQL said: </strong><a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Ferror-messages-server.html" target="mysql_doc"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
</p>
<code>
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
</code><br />
</div>
```

Error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>
> ## Error
>
> SQL query at line 1

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused by one of these MySQL settings being exceeded:

```
wait_timeout
max_allowed_packet
```

Your host or server person needs to increase these settings in MySQL. There is more info here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html