# '<!-- PMA-SQL-ERROR --> when importing db

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to import my database into a new one however I get the following error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `<!-- PMA-SQL-ERROR -->`

```
 <div class="error"><h1>Error</h1>
```

**`SQL query`** at line 1

The error in the exported file is:

```
<!-- PMA-SQL-ERROR -->
    <div class="error"><h1>Error</h1>
<p><strong>SQL query:</strong>
<a       href="tbl_sql.php?sql_query=SHOW+TABLE+STATUS+FROM+%60addcart138an%60+LIKE+%2    7zen_categories%27&amp;show_query=1&amp;db=addcart138an&    amp;table=zen_categories&amp;token=ed1d79622b85c64e6353225dce5738e8"><span     class="nowrap"><img     src="themes/dot.gif" title="Edit" alt="Edit"     class="icon ic_b_edit" /> Edit</span></a>    </p>
<p>
<span class="syntax"><span class="inner_sql"><a href="./url.php?url=http    %3A%2F    %2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Fshow.html&amp;token=ed1d79622b85    c64e6353225dce5738e8" target="mysql_doc"><span class="syntax_alpha     syntax_alpha_reservedWord">SHOW</span></a>  <span class="syntax_alpha     syntax_alpha_reservedWord">TABLE</span>  <span class="syntax_alpha         syntax_alpha_reservedWord">STATUS</span>  <span class="syntax_alpha     syntax_alpha_reservedWord">FROM</span>  <span class="syntax_quote     syntax_quote_backtick">`addcart138an`</span>  <a href="./url.php?url=http    %3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Fstring-comparison-    functions.html%23operator_like&amp;token=ed1d79622b85c64e6353225dce5738e8"     target="mysql_doc"><span class="syntax_alpha     syntax_alpha_reservedWord">LIKE</span></a>  <span class="syntax_quote     syntax_quote_single">'zen_categories'</span></span></span>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>MySQL said: </strong><a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F    %2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Ferror-messages-    server.html&amp;token=ed1d79622b85c64e6353225dce5738e8"     target="mysql_doc"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation"     alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
</p>
<code>
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
</code><br />
</div>
```

I have tried exporting the first db again and also tried changing the settings for the export however I keep receiving the same error.

When I open the sql file I can see that the error code is at the bottom of the page, when deleted I don't get an error message but only a few of the db tables are actually imported.

I have tried searching for the answer, however the only relevant question I found has no answers.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381304/pma-sql-error-while-importing-database/31652382#31652382
See my answer there.

Answer (score 11):

I have faced this problem while export the database and founded the solution for this error. This error occurred due to large amount of data in your database tables and less php execution time. To resolve this go to your hosting account as I have godaddy hosting account -> Cpanel then under Files section click on Back & Resort  and get the mysql database backup.   It will show you all the databases with download option. Click on the database to download the zip file like yourdatabase.sql.gz . It is the compressed and light weight (in terms of size) package. when downloaded extract it and import it on phpmyadmin.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the easy solution! :) Great Help.

Answer (score 8):

1. just open your sql backup file in any text editor
2. find    `<!-- PMA-SQL-ERROR -->
   <div class="error"><h1>Error</h1>`  (may be this code at end of file)
3. delete that all non sql code from sql file
4. Save file

may this help for some one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I don't really know what happened, but I tried again today (about a week later) and it worked. Although I did notice that the sql file I downloaded today was quite large (a bit over 21 MB), so I was thinking this could have something to do with it. Maybe the server was already over loaded by other users on that specific day and maybe my hosting service changed something. I really don't know, but to anyone who comes along a similar problem I would suggest to contact their hosting service, I'm almost sure this would help and it is what I was going to do if the db didn't load correctly today as well.
Good day to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you have issue while exporting your database. It means your sql file is not exported properly. So its better to export your database in parts like 5 tables at a time